# What's with the Hungarian notation in jQuery DataTable option names?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

In my opinion, Hungarian Notation is for the most part history. Yet, in a good sample of tutorials and examples for the jQuery DataTable widget, Hungarian is used, and others straight, 'untyped' naming is used. Is this just a preference, or are the Hungarian style names somehow different to the non-Hungarian ones?

For example, here, from the official documentation, the simple and readable array name `columns` is used:

```
$('#example').dataTable( {
    "columns": [
      { "width": "20%" },
    null,
    ...
  ]
} );
```

Yet here, Hungarian notation is used. A young novice might really be tripped up by `aoColumns`, where even I can only guess it means an `array of objects`.

```
$("#ratesandcharges1").dataTable({
    "bRetrieve": false,
    ...
    "aaSorting": [[2, "desc"]],
    "aoColumns": [
    { sWidth: '9%' },
    ...
    { sWidth: '10%' } ]
    });

    ratesandcharges1.fnDraw();

});
```

Comment: *"Is this just a preference, or are the Hungarian style names somehow different to the non-Hungarian ones?"* - The names have no effect on how those properties behave, so it must just be a preference of whoever wrote it. (As an aside, I think it's weird that they've used quotes around most of the property names but not all of them.)

Comment: The reversed naming is still popular in Asian countries but am not sure if it applies to computer science.

Comment: @Betterdev Reversed?

Comment: @ProfK:The Wikipedia article.

Comment: People, Betterdev refers to an article on Hungarian notation that implies it might be so called because Hungarian names are reversed, i.e. the family, or surname, occurs before the first name. Thank you Betterdev, slightly off-topic but quite interesting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Modern versions of DataTables ( > 1.10) generally use Camel Case names but note:

> the old Hungarian notation syntax still included for backwards
>   compatibility so your tables won't simply break when you update from
>   an older version of DataTales.

Please check this [page](https://datatables.net/upgrade/1.10-naming) as on it Allan notes:

> Hungarian notation is an anathema to many developers, however, when I
>   wrote the first version of DataTables, the company I was working for
>   then had strict coding standards that required the use of Hungarian
>   notation, so I was "trained" in its use, hence why it is present.

I prefer putting properties in quotes (usually double quotes ;-) ) personally and go through code adding them, I know that they're not required but they seem more JSONie if they're there... that's just me though.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Hehe, the quotes thing sounds like something I would also do.